# Read data separated by tab from file

Tags: python, file

If I have the following file:

```
Pig
06-13-01    56.2
06-13-02    59.2
06-13-03    54.3
.
.
.
Cow
06-13-01   201.2
06-13-02   204.1
06-13-03   205.6
.
.
.
```

and want to create an instance of an object with the data for the animal with the associated date and weight (value seperated by tab). How do I do that in my main program?

I have begun with this:

```
  with open(filnamn, encoding="utf-8") as file:
dateAndWeight = []
lines = fil.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]
stepsBetweenName = 68
numberOfAnimals = int(len(lines)/stepsBetweenName)`
```

But this is just the beginning. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Are you able to alter how this data is delivered/saved? It would be tremendously easier if the animal type is it's own column instead of it's own line per group.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? You say "object per animal", One option is a 3 column table with animal name, date and weight. Another would be a dictionary that maps animal name to 2 column lists of date and weight.

Comment: I need to access the date and weight in my main program, for example in order to find the highest and lowest weight during the period. I don't know the easiest method to do that but storing them as instances of a class seems decent?

Answer (score 1):

Your data alternates between animal name and tab separated data. This is a good fit for `itertools.groupby` which creates its own iterators based on a condition such as column count.

In this example, `groupby` starts a new sub-iteration whenever the row count changes between 1 and not-1. When its 1, you know you have a new animal. When not-1, you have rows of data. Here, I just built a dictionary that maps animal name to its date/weight info.

```
import itertools
import io
import csv

# test file

file = io.StringIO("""Pig
06-13-01\t56.2
06-13-02\t59.2
06-13-03\t54.3
Cow
06-13-01\t201.2
06-13-02\t204.1
06-13-03\t205.6""")

# will hold `animal:[[date, weight], ...]` associations
animal_map = {}

# data is TSV file
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")

# Group by rows of length 1 which start a new set of animal date, weight pairs
for new_animal, rows in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda row: len(row) == 1):
    if new_animal:
        # get animal from first row
        animal = next(rows)[0]
    else:
        # add animal and data to map
        animal_map[animal] = list(rows)
        del animal

print(animal_map)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the animal_map just prints out {}, how do I get it to print animal:[[date, weight], ...] like your described?

Comment: How do I do if I have a file and not a StringIO? Say my file name is "animaldata.txt", what should I do then?

Comment: Do your `with open(filnamn, encoding="utf-8") as file:` to read from a file. The StringIO thing is just for a working demo.

Comment: It prints `{'Pig': [['06-13-01', '56.2'], ['06-13-02', '59.2'], ['06-13-03', '54.3']], 'Cow': [['06-13-01', '201.2'], ['06-13-02', '204.1'], ['06-13-03', '205.6']]}` for me. Not sure what hte difference is for you.

Comment: Yeah it worked fine now. The only problem I have is when I add new animals to the text file (with new data in the same format), they don't show up in the dictionary. Why is that do you believe?